# Аниматор и анимации, Legacy, проблема

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Хочу сделать анимацию при клике и при смерти моба. Весь код у меня в одном скрипте, скрипт на мэйнКамере.

Вот это мне пишет Юнити 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой аниматор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Анимация, которая после входа работает(Mob2Anim), но если кликнуть, то анимация клика(ClickAnim) срабатывает всего 1 раз и больше на клики не реагирует, а анимация смерти(Death) вообще не работает.

В скрипте вызываю анимации вот так:
Синтаксис:

```
        Mobs[CurrentMob].GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Death");

        Mobs[CurrentMob].GetComponent<Animator>().Play("ClickAnim");
```

Эти строки в скрипте onClick, который вызывается при нажатии на моба. Сами мобы в массиве Mobs[]
Если что, при переводе анимаций в легаси, их будет нельзя добавить в аниматор.
Если что, при переводе анимаций в легаси, как просит предупреждение,  их будет нельзя добавить в аниматор.
Вот если что еще скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу пожалуйста помочь, либо с этим, либо подсказать способ, как использовать несколько анимаций для одного объекта.